# "Variable might not have been initialized" error

Tags: java, if-statement, io, jvm, switch-statement

My compiler won't have it. :( Now what? Do I have to completely rewrite the entire app?

To see the line which my compiler is rejecting, do a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> search for System.out.println(celsiusOutput + " C");

When trying to compile, I'm told by the compiler, "variable celsiusOutput might not have been initialized." The compiler does not say the same thing about either of the two other output terms: fahrenheitOutput and kelvinOutput.

```
/** 
 * The Temperature class prints the conversion of an inputted temperature value
 * from one of the three temperature scales -- C, F or K -- to all three,
 * unless the input is illegal.
 */

import java.util.Scanner;
public class Temperature
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Declaration of output terms;
        double celsiusOutput;
        double fahrenheitOutput;
        double kelvinOutput;

        // Printing request for input terms from the user + reception of said terms
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Welcome to the temperature scale converter.");
        System.out.println("Please enter your input temperature scale and degree value in the following format:");
        System.out.println("\"A n∈ℝ\", where A is the first letter of your scale (C, F or K) and n∈ℝ is the degrees.");
        String input = scan.next().toUpperCase(); 
            char inputScale = input.charAt(0);
        double inputDegrees = scan.nextDouble();

        // Declaration of final terms, i.e. the conversion formulae:
        final double C_DEGREES_IN_F = (inputDegrees - 32.00) / 1.80;
            final double C_DEGREES_IN_K = inputDegrees + 273.15;
        final double F_DEGREES_IN_C = (inputDegrees - 32.00) / 1.80;
            final double F_DEGREES_IN_K = (inputDegrees + 459.67) / 1.80;
        final double K_DEGREES_IN_C = inputDegrees - 273.15;
            final double K_DEGREES_IN_F = (inputDegrees - 273.15) * 1.80 + 32.00;

        // Conditional assignment of output terms, as conditioned by the user's input terms
        if(inputScale == 'C')
            celsiusOutput = inputDegrees;
            fahrenheitOutput = F_DEGREES_IN_C;
            kelvinOutput = K_DEGREES_IN_C;
        if(inputScale == 'F')
            celsiusOutput = C_DEGREES_IN_F;
            fahrenheitOutput = inputDegrees;
            kelvinOutput = K_DEGREES_IN_F;
        if(inputScale == 'K')
            celsiusOutput = C_DEGREES_IN_K;
            fahrenheitOutput = F_DEGREES_IN_K;
            kelvinOutput = inputDegrees;

        // Printing of output terms + legality check
        switch(inputScale)
        {
            case 'C':
            case 'F':
            case 'K':
                System.out.println(celsiusOutput + " C");
                System.out.println(fahrenheitOutput + " F");
                System.out.println(kelvinOutput + " K");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Illegal input.");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No. You initialize the variable. Which variable? `double celsiusOutput = 0;` That's an initial value.

Comment: Your ifs need braces.

Comment: "The compiler does not say the same thing about either of the two other output terms: fahrenheitOutput and kelvinOutput." That's because you've made a *second* mistake, which is to assume that indentation is significant - your `if` statements should have braces around the bodies.

Comment: give celsiusOutput  a value of 0 before you start the logic because if it doesn't match any of the conditions then it isn't initialized.

Comment: Success! Thanks, y'all :D

Answer (score 4):

You need an initialisation of the variable change double `double celsiusOutput;` into `double celsiusOutput = 0;`. Also there are braces in if statements needed for the algorithm to work. The correct one would be:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Temperature
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Declaration of output terms;
        double celsiusOutput = 0;
        double fahrenheitOutput = 0;
        double kelvinOutput = 0;

        // Printing request for input terms from the user + reception of said terms
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Welcome to the temperature scale converter.");
        System.out.println("Please enter your input temperature scale and degree value in the following format:");
        System.out.println("\"A n∈ℝ\", where A is the first letter of your scale (C, F or K) and n∈ℝ is the degrees.");
        String input = scan.next().toUpperCase();
        char inputScale = input.charAt(0);
        double inputDegrees = scan.nextDouble();

        // Declaration of final terms, i.e. the conversion formulae:
        final double C_DEGREES_IN_F = (inputDegrees - 32.00) / 1.80;
        final double C_DEGREES_IN_K = inputDegrees + 273.15;
        final double F_DEGREES_IN_C = (inputDegrees - 32.00) / 1.80;
        final double F_DEGREES_IN_K = (inputDegrees + 459.67) / 1.80;
        final double K_DEGREES_IN_C = inputDegrees - 273.15;
        final double K_DEGREES_IN_F = (inputDegrees - 273.15) * 1.80 + 32.00;

        // Conditional assignment of output terms, as conditioned by the user's input terms
        if(inputScale == 'C') {
            celsiusOutput = inputDegrees;
            fahrenheitOutput = F_DEGREES_IN_C;
            kelvinOutput = K_DEGREES_IN_C;
        }
        if(inputScale == 'F') {
            celsiusOutput = C_DEGREES_IN_F;
            fahrenheitOutput = inputDegrees;
            kelvinOutput = K_DEGREES_IN_F;
        }
        if(inputScale == 'K') {
            celsiusOutput = C_DEGREES_IN_K;
            fahrenheitOutput = F_DEGREES_IN_K;
            kelvinOutput = inputDegrees;
        }

        // Printing of output terms + legality check
        switch(inputScale)
        {
            case 'C':
            case 'F':
            case 'K':
                System.out.println(celsiusOutput + " C");
                System.out.println(fahrenheitOutput + " F");
                System.out.println(kelvinOutput + " K");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Illegal input.");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also initialize the others: 
        double fahrenheitOutput = 0;
        double kelvinOutput = 0;
Else he gets compile error on the next line :-)

Comment: Actually, there is not - they are not covered with braces in if statements. With initialization of only celsiusOutput the code compiles. I admit, it is needed, then braces added.

Answer (score 3):

You made two mistakes:

1. If `inputScale` is neither 'C', 'F' or 'K', none of your three variables are initialized, hence the error. You can fix this by initializing them with a dummy value (`double celsiusOutput = 0;`).
2. Your error only shows for `celsiusOutput` because when you don't add any braces after an `if` statement, that `if` will only affect the next command; in this case, `celsiusOutput = inputDegrees` for your first `if`. The other two lines will be executed, no matter what. Just add braces around the lines you want to be affected by the `if` statement.